# Passing data to my custom NSObject?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

I have attempted to create my first custom class "AudioPlayer". I want to pass data (the audio title) from a tableview to my "AudioPlayer" and load the AudioPlayer with  **initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]** but when I alloc the "AudioPlayer" in my "MainViewController" i get the error "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'Audio  Player*___strong' with and expression of type AVAudioPLayer*". My question is, How would i initialize my custom audio player with the selected audio's title as the URL? It works fine when I created a variable of AVAudioPlayer, but I don't know how to pass it to my custom class.

Here is my custom class Header..

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface AudioPlayer : NSObject{

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

    //Volume slider
    NSTimer *volumeTimer;
    IBOutlet UISlider *volumeSlider;
}

-(bool) isPlaying;
-(bool) isPaused;

-(void)playPause:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

@end
```

Here is my custom class implementation file...

```
#import "AudioPlayer.h"

@implementation AudioPlayer

@synthesize audioPlayer;

-(void)playPause{

    if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {

        [audioPlayer pause];

    } else { 

        [audioPlayer play];

    }
}

-(void)volumeSlider
{
    //Setup the volume slider
    volumeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(updateVolumeSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [audioPlayer setVolume:volumeSlider.value];
}
@end
```

Here is the MainView implementation...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Instantiate performanceArray
    performanceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Centering", nil];

    //Instantiate recoveryArray
    recoveryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Power Nap", nil];

    //Instantiate the AudioPlayer
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:cell.textLabel.text ofType:@"m4a"];
    AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];    
    [audioPlayer.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AudioPlayer object that you created is not of type AVAudioPlayer so I think the following line:
AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

should be something like :  AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];

which would create an object of your custom class. You have at least a couple of options to then pass the NSURL information such as adding params to your custom classes init method or creating another property  in your custom class that you set just after you create your object.

In your custom class AudioPlayer you could add a new my URL attribute:

```
@interface AudioPlayer : NSObject{

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

    //Volume slider
    NSTimer *volumeTimer;
    IBOutlet UISlider *volumeSlider;
    NSURL* myURL;
}
```

Then in your implementation file for AudioPlayer add the following init method:

```
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL)theURL
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       // perform initialization of object here
       myURL = theURL;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then in your MainView you could do something like:

```
NSURL* theURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] initWithURL:theURL];
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me a quick example of passing the url?

Comment: Im getting the error "No know instance method for selector 'error' on     **NSURL* theURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];**  and Receiver type 'AudioPlayer' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'initWitURL:' on **    AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] initWitURL:theURL];
**

Comment: I managed to fix a few things on my own but with your code **AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] initWithURL:theURL];** I get the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: I believe it should be **initWithContentsOfURL**??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing your custom class with AVAudioPlayer class.
If you are trying to add more methods and options to the default class of AVAudioPlayer, you should subclass AVAudioPlayer rather than NSObject.

> ```
> #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
> #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
> #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
>
> @interface AudioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer
> // the rest of your code
> ```

and then as **deanandreakis** answered, you need to alloc/init your class rather than AVAudioPlayer.

meaning:

> ```
> AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
> ```

Or you can use [categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) to add your custom methods added to AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, looks like I have some studying to do. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: How would I tell my custom class to play the selected audio? I know how to do it with the avaudioplayer class but not my own

Comment: If you do @interface AudioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer, your class inherits all the properties and methods of its parent class, i.e. AVAudioPlayer. So, even if you do nothing, by importing your own class, you will be able to play/pause as you would normally do. Here is some material to read: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Comment: Awesome that opens me up to some other options...Thank you very much!